# Reducing the Amount of Vertical Space Between the Lines of a TOC Subsection Entry

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, vertical-spacing, baseline, subsection

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}

\textwidth=4in
\textheight=6.40in
\voffset -7pt

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\bfseries} \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{\scshape{Section Title}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\textit{A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}}
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I reduce the vertical space between the lines in the TOC subsection entry? Why is there so much vertical space?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the standard method of creating and customizing table of contents is the `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages.

Comment: @User23456234 I tried adding the `titlesec`  and `titletoc` packages, but still the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It uses the  `setspace` package to reduce the baseline skip before the entry subsection in the ToC and expand it after.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}

\textwidth=4in
\textheight=6.40in
\voffset -7pt

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small\bfseries}
 \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\footnotesize\itshape}
 
%********************************************************** adedd <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{setspace} % change the space between lines of text
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{1ex}
    
\makeatletter   
\pretocmd{\l@subsection}
{\setstretch{0.6}} % reduce  baseline skip before subsection entry
{}{}

\apptocmd{\l@subsection}
{\setstretch{1.1}} % expand baseline  skip after subsection entry
{}{}

\makeatother
%**********************************************************

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
            \textbf{\scshape{Section Title I}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title I}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
            \textbf{A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}
    
        \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
            \textbf{\scshape{Section Title II}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title II}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{4in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
            \textbf{Another subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Another subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section. A subsection of the section.}
\end{document}
```

Not related: `\scshape` does not have arguments.

To use  `\scshape\bfseries Section Title I` you need a font that support both. For example add  `\usepackage{libertine}`.

Comment: Thank you for another very fine answer.